# iOS: iMessage style header and divider UI

Tags: ios, uitableview, user-interface

[image]

I'm trying to recreate pieces of the iMessage UI. Specifically the *top buttons* and *dividers* (i.e. "iMessage" label + line)

I'm assuming:

- The *top buttons* are within custom `UIView` as the header of a `UITableView`
- The *divider* is a custom `UITableViewCell` with a centered label and some kind of repeated background image…

Can anyone confirm or elaborate on this? Specifically the *dividers*.

Comment: +1 I'd say your assumptions are probably correct.

Comment: Please know though that creating dotted patterns, and UIColor's +colorWithPatternImage: are two of the most expensive graphics operations known to man.

Comment: @CodaFi, you should elaborate in an answer on how it could be created.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would create the divider and the "iMessage" text as a single image.

Since the divider and the buttons on top of it is "non-sticky" I would just create a custom `UITableViewCell` and put everything (buttons and divider image) in the table cell.

Comment: Note that the *divider* is separate from the header. That is, it's used to divide messages. It's only coincidence that it's paired with the *top buttons* in my example.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary if the divider is separate, then put the divider image in it's own cell.